# Could not set the List property

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have looked for this issue and actually tried to follow some of the solutions but it happens that for some reason it's not working with me.

So I have a dropdown menu (gateway) and a text box (dueDate) and once I select and fill the blank spaces I want to populate a ListBox1 being the 1st column the gateway and 2nd column the dueDate.

this is what I have, but it pops up a window saying:
"Run-time error '381':
Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index."

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'ListBox1.AddItem (gateway.Value)
    ListBox1.List(ListCount - 1, 0) = gateway.Value
    ListBox1.List(ListCount - 1, 1) = dueDate.Value
End Sub
```

I have set the ListBox1 BoundColumn and ColumnCount to 2 in the design editor.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Managed to fix it. Based on the first comment to this thread I have used the following.

```
With ListBox1
    ListCount = .ListCount
    .AddItem gateway.Value
    .List(ListCount, 1) = dueDate.Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed some time to figure this out myself (^.^):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    With ListBox1
        ListCount = .ListCount
        .AddItem gateway.Value, ListCount -1
        .List(ListCount - 1, 0) = dueDate.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Well I just used the information from your first code so I believed this was what you wanted. Happy that it works now :) You should probably mark this as the accepted answer to mark this as finished :)